# When did the term 'leverage' gain its verb/debt-related meaning?

Tags: etymology

I was discussing the much-abused business term *leverage* with a colleague and thought it would be interesting to know when the term as a verb entered popular use as opposed to the physics-related noun.

I can look at ngrams and do basic searches, but since the forms exist as homonyms I don't know of any tools that can distinguish between the two.

When did the word *leverage* become a commonplace way to describe borrowing to make money, and how much newer is it than the physics term?

Comment: Looks like a may have answered the question as no one else has even attempted an answer in 4 months with 90 views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *[leverage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/leverage)*(Word Origin & History section) appears to have first been used in a financial sense in 1937 and as a verb in 1957.

It appears that the difference in years between each words common usage is a [little over 230 years](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1957+-+1724).